# Understanding source and target containers in Docker linking

Tags: docker

I was just reading the Docker doc's on linking , **[HERE](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/)** and came across the following command:

```
$ docker run -d -P --name web --link db:db training/webapp python app.py
```

In the above command a new container is being created I.E. `web` and it is being linked to an existing container , I.E.`db` , now in the documentation the terminology used to explain the above command is `source` container and `target` container.

What does this terminology really mean in the context of the command i have given ? which would be the `source` and which would be the `target` container ? I have having great difficulty understanding this , can somebody explain ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this documentation, the fact they give an example in which the link *alias* has the same name as the container to link to is disturbing.

In the [`docker run` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) we can find less disturbing usage examples.

> ```
> --link=""  : Add link to another container (<name or id>:alias or <name or id>)
> ```

If you already have a container named `db` running a database service, then you could start the following container named `foo`:

```
docker run -d --name foo --link db:potato somedockerimage
```

From the `foo` container, you would then connect to the database with the following configuration string:

```
mysql://potato:3306/somedb
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's take this example, let's assume we have 2 containers:

```
-A
-B
```

the state of A is "not running";
the state of B  is "running";

I want to link A to B, the command is:

```
# linking without alias
docker run --name A --link B ubuntu:latest

# linking with alias
docker run --name A --link B:B_alias ubuntu:latest
```

"graphically" the situation is:

```
B-------A
```

The SOURCE container is B, it already exists and is already running;
The TARGET container that I created and now is running is A;
This terminology makes it easier to distinguish between A and B.

If you inspect the /etc/hosts file of each container you will notice that:
B - hosts file: there is an alias for ip address of A;
A - hosts file: there is an alias for ip address of B;

An example of A's hosts file could be:

```
#/etc/hosts  
...  
127.0.0.1 localhost  
...  
...  
172.17.0.4 B
```

The communication between A and B is bidirectional.
You can ping from B to A and from A to B, let's verify this with this 
command from the host machine:

```
# ping from B to A
docker exec -t B ping A

# ping from A to B
docker exec -t A ping B
```

Finally, from the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/):
"Docker creates a secure tunnel between the containers 
that doesn’t need to expose any ports externally on the container;"
The important part to understand about linking is that **none of 
container's informations needs to be publicly exposed by the linked containers**.

Sources: personal experience and study of [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/)